# how to make HTTPS calls on the iOS simulator Delphi seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

OpenSSL not working for iOS Simulator in Delphi DX
Using info at:
http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/OpenSSL
https://plus.google.com/100777187605111792758/posts/SPnHdXvTTNu

I can get it to work on devices, but not on the iOS simulator. Same URL works when I use a TWebbrowser.navigate, but not with INDY of course.. See below, and possibly offer suggestions on **how to make HTTPS calls on the iOS simulator** ! This worked before in earlier versions of Rad Studio ( XE4, XE5 ) but hasnt since XE7 if my memory has served me right.

I have these files in my usr/lib folder:

```
libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
libssl.0.9.8.dylib
```

Here is my uses

```
uses
  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  {$IF Defined(IOS) and Defined(CPUARM)}
    IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_Static,
  {$ELSE}
    IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
  {$ENDIF}
...
```

Here is my onCreate for the main form

```
procedure TmLoginForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  t:string;
begin
  IdOpenSSLSetLibPath('/usr/lib/');
...
```

Here is part of a function that I use, where on the last line an exception is thrown

```
function ParseGroups(OnlyUserCreated:boolean):integer;
var
  IdHTTP          :TIdHTTP;
  HTML            :String;
  JSON_Groups     :TJSONObject;
  Group           :uGroup;
begin
  result:=0;
  HTML:='';
  IdHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.HandleRedirects:=false;
  try
    HTML:=IdHTTP.Get(URL_Host+ACCESSTOKEN);
```

Error is: 'Could Not Load SSL Library'

`ShowMessage(IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad);` shows a blank message

Update:

adding

```
 IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load;
```

after setting the path now causes the whichFailedToLoad say: 'Failed to Load /usr/lib/libcrypto.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) instead of the Indy components.

```
var
  http : THTTPClient;
  html : string;

http := THTTPClient.Create;
try
  html := http.Get( url ).ContentAsString();
  ...
finally
  http.Free;
end;
```

It is a wrapper of the http function from the operating system. If the OS supports https, then this class will do also.

Comment: As long as you do not want to [abort the request](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12879), you are fine with this :o)

Comment: @SirRufo -- there are some issues/problems if i want to terminate/abort HTTP request?

Comment: @Zam The link will lead you to the bug report

Comment: i got `ENETHTTPRequestException , message : client not assigned to request component` error on android.

Answer (score 2):

You can also follow this nifty blogpost http://delphiworlds.com/2016/03/building-openssl-dylibs-for-ios-simulator/

It worked just fine for me. I needed it, because my Soap client needs to connect via https, and I did not want to rewrite the soap libs.

Comment: I'll be revisiting that article this week, as someone seems to be having troubles with Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Comment: @DaveNottage: Nice to hear that. I'm looking forward to reading it.

Comment: @DaveNottage ;) Happy to hear that!

Comment: I should read my own comments on the article; I already checked Berlin. Mind you, I've now checked Tokyo and all good there, too

Comment: @DaveNottage - I tried following your instructions for Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1 and OpenSSL 1.1.0f and the script fails. It finishes the 2 buildMac calls and then errors at "Copying headers... cp:/tmp/openssl-1.1.0f-i386/include/openssl/*: No such file or directory. I checked the /tmp/openssl-1.1.0f-i386 folder and there is no include directory there. Could you please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Rohit You're not doing anything wrong; it appears something has changed in the make files for OpenSSL that means the files the script is trying to copy are not there to begin with. I've tried changing the script so that it just copies the headers from the extracted files, however the build for the iOS x86_64 version fails. It's now a matter of working out why

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNottage. I did try to copy the header files from the tar extract, but that did not work (as you have also corroborated). Would appreciate it if you could let me know if you figure it out and resolve this.

Comment: Do you definitely need to use 1.10f? I've checked 1.0.2l and the script works with that. In the meantime, I'll see if I can find a fix

Comment: @Rohit I think I have fixed the script, based on a fork of the original script that I found. I've put the new script here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Scripts/openssl-build-shared.sh. I haven't tested the resulting dylibs as yet. Make sure you have the Xcode command line tools installed.

Comment: @DaveNottage - I don't think I necessarily need 1.1.0f - I just picked that up since it was the most current stable release. I will give your revised script a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help with this!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153415/discussion-between-dave-nottage-and-rohit).